# Android Toolbar in all activities

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a toolbar which has a notification icon with a count badge. My problem is if i implement a new toolbar in all activities the badge count is not synchronized. How can i solve this ? Any links or tutorials appreciated.

Comment: why you are making tool bar in all activity.. just use BaseActivity pattern.

Comment: Will i get the same menu items and the same badge count if i use BaseActivity ?

Comment: of course .. you have to maintain it.

Comment: Okay let me try, Thanks

Comment: just create the BaseActivity and create one method in BaseActivity which accept the Integer counter. And call this method from all activity...

Comment: yes.. no need of toolbar.. getSupportActionBar is the best solution for that..

Answer (score 1):

If all your Activities are a subclass of a "`BaseActivity`"which cointains the toolbar and code to update the badge that should do the trick.

Also you should store the current value on the badge in `SharedPreferences` and update it to the badge on the `BaseActivity` `onResume()` for example.